# Material-ui <Table/> throw an Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Im having an hard time with material-ui Table (which I used dozen of times in my previous projects).

I am currently using `@material-ui/core@3.5.1`, i also tried with `@3.2.0` and `@3.6.0`.

I am also using `react@16.3.2` and `react-dom@16.2.0`

I have some other components (Button, TextField...) from material-ui in my project which works perfectly, however, when I try to use the `SimpleTable` example I have the following error:

[image: error]

I tried to used it in a brand new project => It works.

That's why I tried to switch from a version to an other but it's still not working. I cannot figured out where is my mistake :(.

Here is the my SimpleTable Component (perfect copy/past from mui documentation):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        overflowX: 'auto'
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 700
    }
});

let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
    id += 1;
    return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
    const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table className={classes.table}>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Calories</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Fat (g)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Carbs (g)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Protein (g)</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map(row => {
                        return (
                            <TableRow key={row.id}>
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                    {row.name}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{row.calories}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{row.fat}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{row.protein}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        );
                    })}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

I am using it as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import SimpleTable from './Table';

export const MyPage = () => (
    <div>       
        <SimpleTable />
    </div>
);
```

I'm using MyPage directly under the theme provider in the App `render()`

```
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <MyPage />        
 </MuiThemeProvider>
```

I have some other page which works with other material-ui components.

If I changed the rendering of SimpleTable just to return a `<p>Hello World</p>` instead of the whole table stuff, it's working. So it cannot come from the default export or from the global import of the  component imo.
It might come from my material-ui import.. but they seem alright..

If anyone have an idea, some help would be really appreciate overhere <3

PS: I tried to start my comment with "Hi" or "Hello" but it seems he's automatically erased from my post x)

Comment: how are you using `MyPage`?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with material-ui.It's just a problem with the way you import/export or declare component.

Comment: I edited my post, but I am using it exactly as I'm using my other components.

Comment: If I changed the rendering of `SimpleTable` just to return a `<p>Hello World</p>` instead of the whole table stuff, it's working. So it cannot come from the default export or from the global import of the `<SimpleTable>` component imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to came from a conflict with react-native-web which is used elsewhere in the project.

Updating `react-native-web` + installing `react-art` solved the issue.